# Google Maps API for the community photos at the bottom of Google Maps Satellite view?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

In the DOM they are reviewed to as *runway card view*.
I have an web platform idea which would be using these photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Google Places API can help here.  The content probably won't be same as the runway on google.com/map but you might be able to get some interesting photos for nearby places and build a similar experience.

Using a [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) request you could find a list of places around your map, sending the center point of your map as the location or even a category if you're interesting in something specific.  The place results from that call should include some `photo_reference`'s which can be fed into a [Place Photos](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) request to get photos for each place.